# How to turn on icloud sharing on Production environment?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I have a key in `Myapp.entitlements`:

```
com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment
```

and value: `Development`.

With above when I try to share the record using `UICloudSharingController` then everything is fine, and it is shared. But when I change above key to `Production` what is intended for me, it doesn't work.

Always got a response:

`Failed to modify some records`. What is going on?

Should I somewhere turn it on? A new entity in cloudkit dashboard or something else?

The exact error is:

```
Optional(<CKError 0x1c144b520: "Partial Failure" (2/1011); "Failed to modify some records"; uuid = 7580FED7-25A0-430C-A16C-610A506F4309; container ID = "iCloud.pl.blueworld.fieldservice"; partial errors: {
Share-54BD438F-BA4F-46EE-8B71-403CFA780D3F:(fieldservice:__defaultOwner__) = <CKError 0x1c1448c10: "Invalid Arguments" (12/2006); server message = "Cannot create a new type in production schema"; uuid = 7580FED7-25A0-430C-A16C-610A506F4309>
... 1 "Batch Request Failed" CKError's omitted ...
}>)
```

Answer (score 0):

This line in the error message looks like the problem:

> server message = "Cannot create a new type in production schema";

It looks like you haven't deployed your (latest) schema from the dev environment to the prod environment in the cloudkit dashboard. You've just told your app to look at the prod environment.